# Validating input with Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I need to validate input to my application. The input is a formatted string that may contain parts of a Date, e.g.:

```
{0:yy}{0:MM}{0:dd}_{0:hh}{0:mm}{0:ss}-SOME OTHER TEXT
sometext{0:yyyy}{0:MM}{0:dd}mORETEXT
```

The input doesn't have to contain those parts of a date, but if it does, I need them to be valid format items that can be used by `String.Format()` method. I believe I should validate using `Regular Expressions`, but I am not good at it.

Could you please help?

Comment: So you're trying to parse dates out of an arbitrary string?  Or are you doing assertive validation?

Comment: I am not sure what assertive validation is. I store these strings in the database, and use them in my C# code like this: FileName = String.Format(dr["FileNameTemplate"].ToString(), DateTime.UtcNow)

Comment: So I don't want the user to enter invalid format item like "SomeText{garbage}moreText{moregarbage}theend"

Comment: That sounds like parsing, then.  By "assertive validation" I meant putting on the brakes and telling the user "no, that's not valid - fix it".

Comment: So if the string contains single curly brace, there must be a closing brace, and between them there must be "0:" plus a valid part of a DateTime. I mean valid to be used as a format item in C#'s String.Format() method.

Comment: There are a ton of date/time formats in the world.  Is what you've shown examples the universe of formats that you expect to have to handle?

Comment: So far I have yy, yyyy,MM, dd, hh, mm, ss... I may have more in the future, but so far this is it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given our back-and-forth via comments, I think the what you are looking for is:

```
        Regex curlyThings = new Regex(@"\{0:.*?\}");
        Regex kosherCurlyThings = new Regex(@"\{0:(yy|yyyy|MM|dd|hh|mm|ss)\}");

        MatchCollection matchCollection = curlyThings.Matches("CG{0:yyyy}-{0:MM}-{0:dd}asdf{0:GARBAGE}.csv");
        foreach(Match match in matchCollection)
        {
            if(!kosherCurlyThings.IsMatch(match.Value))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} isn't kosher!", match.Value);
            }                
        }
```

Comment: You probably want to escape `{` and `}` characters since they're special characters in regexes.

Comment: @jonnyGold Hmmm... Something goes wrong. I tried to test this with the following code:

Comment: var r = new Regex(@".*?(\{0:yy(yy)?\}\{0:MM\}\{0:dd\}(_\{0:hh\}\{0:mm\}\{0:ss\}))?.*?");
            if (!r.IsMatch("CG{0:yyyGARBAGEy}-{0:MM}-{0:dd}.csv"))
            {
                var blah = "The format is invalid!";
            }

Comment: But it my bad string was found valid... Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I just debugged it... I misplaced a paren.  I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: @jonnyGold Thanks. But now a valid string "CG{0:yyyy}-{0:MM}-{0:dd}.csv" is said to be invalid...

Comment: I didn't notice the hypens between your tokens until just now.

Comment: @jonnyGold Does it mean you have to specify every character that can happen? Because it can be anything between and around those format items within curly braces. If you didn't specify letters, why do you have to specify hyphens? Thanks.

Comment: Gotcha... didn't realize that. Put a .*? between them, then.

Comment: @jonnyGold But they may be in any order. Also, what about those periods and underscores? Should they be specified in the Regex?

Comment: I think at this point you need to rethink your requirements and supply them in full.  It sounds like you want a set of regexes, not a single one.

Comment: @jonnyGold I don't know how many of them I need. The requirements are the following: there is a string that may contain any characters. If within that string happens a "{" character, there must be the closing "}" character after it, and between them should be nothing except "0:yyyy", "0:yy", "0:MM", "0:dd", "0:hh", "0:mm", "0:ss". Is it possible with Regex at all? Thanks.

Comment: @jonnyGold I am getting an error: parsing "\{0:(yy|yyyy|MM|dd|hh|mm|ss\}" - Not enough )'s.

Comment: @jonnyGold I added a ")" like this: \{0:(yy|yyyy|MM|dd|hh|mm|ss)\} Is that correct? If yes, it still doesn't work properly. If I have a string which has a valid format item e.g. "{0:MM}" and an invalid item e.g. "{0:GARBAGE}", IsMatch() returns true. I guess it is because it found a match. I guess it is all Regex can do for me, right?

Comment: Inverse Regexes, which is what you are looking for, are difficult to implement.

Comment: I just thought of a better answer that should work... take a look.